# Unable to copy using shell_exec

Tags: php, shell

```
 <?php
$src="/var/www/html/test7/sites/default/files/institute.png";
$dest="/var/www/html/test7/sites/default/files/182020/";
shell_exec("cp -r $src $dest");

echo "<H2>Copy files completed!</H2>"; //output when done
?>
```

I am unable copy using shell_exec. I am getting the below error.Please assist.

```
cp: cannot stat '/var/www/html/test7/sites/default/files/institute.png': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Path to institute.png is wrong. Why do you use a _shell_exec_ command instead of [copy() function](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.copy.php)

Comment: Even if i put a full path i gets the same error. i.e http://localhost/test7/sites/default/files/institute.png

Comment: I have to create directory further based on condition, hence using the shell.

Comment: Maybe the webserver is running in a chroot environment. So you need to use pathnames relative to its local root.

Comment: @barmar could you please post the example.

Comment: Post what example? I don't know the configuration of your server.

Comment: @barmar It is creating directory fine at $src by using shell_exec("mkdir -p ".$basepath); where basepath is /var/www/html/test7/sites/default/files/. but cp function giving that error

Comment: Then it must be that the `institute.png` file doesn't exist in that directory.

Comment: BTW, why are you using the `-r` option when you're just copying a single file? That's for copying a directory recursively.

Comment: If the script created the directory, how would there already be files in it?

Comment: mkdir was just a example i have created folder 182020 with that. institute.png is already present in files. I have viewed it many times.

Comment: @barmar i have removed -r  and tried using -a / -v as well it is still giving the same error

Comment: Why would you expect the error to go away? The file doesn't exist, changing the options won't fix that.

Comment: No such file or directory (with full path). Have you taken a look to see if exists such a file?